# JBoss return org.jboss.remoting.ProtocolException: Too many channels open

Tags: jboss, connection, jndi, remote-access, channel

My program encountered a error:

> "org.jboss.remoting3.ProtocolException: Too many channels open"

I have search from internet for some solutions to fix this error.Unfortunately, the suggestions from others is not working for me.

Below is the Code on how I call the jndi remote and the properties that I have used.

```
public static void createUser(String loginID) throws Exception {

    Hashtable props = new Hashtable();
    try {
        props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
        props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "remote://" + localhost:4447);
        props.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", "true");
        props.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "userJBoss");
        props.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");

        context = new InitialContext(props);
        context.lookup("ejb:/createUserOperation/CreateUserGenerator!password.api.CreateUserService");
         .....
         ......
        LOGGER.info("DONE");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("ERROR");
    } finally {
        context.close();
    }
}
```

Due to some certain reason I am not able to show all the content of the method.

The "createUser" will be call everytime when there is a needed of create new user. It will be call up to hundred or thousand time.

I did always close the connection when every time it finish execute the method.

Let say I have call the method for 100 times, some of the users will be created successfully whereas some of the users will be failed.

Error below will prompt to me:

```
2014-12-04 17:23:23,026 - ERROR [Remoting "config-based-naming-client-endpoint" task-4] (org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.RemotingConnectionEJBReceiver- Line:134)  - Failed to open channel for context EJBReceiverContext{clientContext=org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext@bbaebd6, receiver=Remoting connection EJB receiver [connection=Remoting connection <78e43506>,channel=jboss.ejb,nodename=webdev01]} org.jboss.remoting3.ProtocolException: Too many channels open
```

Once the error occurred, it required me to restart my jboss.And it comes again after sometimes.

Appreciate it if anyone wound able to help on my problem faced.

Thanks

Comment: Depending on the version of jboss you can increase the value in the configuration of the remote connector, Eg `<option name="org.jboss.remoting3.RemotingOptions.MAX_OUTBOUND_MESSAGES" value="1234"/>` see: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-4372, https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-4373 and https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-3884

Comment: HI Federico, thanks for ur suggestion.
I am using Jboss 7.1.1, and i didn't set any MAX_OUTBOUND_MESSAGES before in standalone.xml. Do your know what is the default MAX_OUTBOUND_MESSAGES?

Comment: looks like default value is picked up from [RemotingOptions.java]( https://github.com/jboss-remoting/jboss-remoting/blob/2d7273392a571560e77b9eee25565fb46d3dbadd/src/main/java/org/jboss/remoting3/RemotingOptions.java)

Answer (score 0):

You are using mixture of context properties.

This should be enough

```
    final Properties ejbProperties = new Properties();
    ejbProperties.put("remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED", "false");
    ejbProperties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
    ejbProperties.put("remote.connections", "1");
    ejbProperties.put("remote.connection.1.host", "localhost");
    ejbProperties.put("remote.connection.1.port", "4447");

    ejbProperties.put("remote.connection.1.username", "ejbuser");
    ejbProperties.put("remote.connection.1.password", "ejbuser123!");

    final EJBClientConfiguration ejbClientConfiguration = new PropertiesBasedEJBClientConfiguration(ejbProperties);
    final ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector selector = new ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector(ejbClientConfiguration);
    EJBClientContext.setSelector(selector);

    final Context context = new InitialContext(ejbProperties);

// lookup
Foo proxy = context.lookup("ejb:/createUserOperation/CreateUserGenerator!password.api.CreateUserService");
```

when using `org.jboss.ejb.client.naming` it creates `EJBClientContext` object.

When closing `context` you are closing `InitialContext` not `EJBClientContext`

to close `EJBClientContext`:

```
EJBClientContext.getCurrent().close();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a [known JBoss bug](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/EJBCLIENT-84) (EAP 6, AS 7) whereby opening and closing too many [InitialContext](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/naming/InitialContext.html) instances too quickly causes the following error:

> ERROR: Failed to open channel for context EJBReceiverContext

Instead of:

```java
final Properties properties = ...
final Context context = new InitialContext( properties );
```

Try caching the context for a set of properties instead:

```java
private Map<Integer, InitialContext> initialContexts = new HashMap<>();
final Context context = getInitialContext(properties);

private InitialContext getInitialContext(final Properties properties) throws Exception {
    final Integer hash = properties.hashCode();

    InitialContext result = initialContexts.get(hash);

    if (result == null) {
        result = new InitialContext(properties);
        initialContexts.put(hash, result);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Remember to call `close()` when the context is no longer necessary.